# How can I display a page beside a sidebar when I click on the menu item?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a sidebar (I used this from Bootstrap [Bootstrap sidebars](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/examples/sidebars/)). When I click on an item in the menu, I'd like to see the related page on the right side of the sidebar, so I'd like to see it where all that white space is. I don't know if you need React or if you can just do it with JavaScript code, but I believe JavaScript alone is enough.

**PROBLEM**: problem is that it opens full screen, consequently the sidebar disappears, because it is contained in the index.html.

Currently, to test, I've created a page called `try.html` which opens when I click **Home > Overview**.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

How can I display the try.html page on the right side of the sidebar? Is there anyone who can help me? Thank you

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-bs-theme="auto">
  <head><script src="../assets/js/color-modes.js"></script>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.112.5">
    <title>Sidebars · Bootstrap v5.3</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/examples/sidebars/">

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    

    

<link href="../assets/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


    
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="sidebars.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>


    
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
  <symbol id="bootstrap" viewBox="0 0 118 94">
    <title>Bootstrap</title>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M24.509 0c-6.733 0-11.715 5.893-11.492 12.284.214 6.14-.064 14.092-2.066 20.577C8.943 39.365 5.547 43.485 0 44.014v5.972c5.547.529 8.943 4.649 10.951 11.153 2.002 6.485 2.28 14.437 2.066 20.577C12.794 88.106 17.776 94 24.51 94H93.5c6.733 0 11.714-5.893 11.491-12.284-.214-6.14.064-14.092 2.066-20.577 2.009-6.504 5.396-10.624 10.943-11.153v-5.972c-5.547-.529-8.934-4.649-10.943-11.153-2.002-6.484-2.28-14.437-2.066-20.577C105.214 5.894 100.233 0 93.5 0H24.508zM80 57.863C80 66.663 73.436 72 62.543 72H44a2 2 0 01-2-2V24a2 2 0 012-2h18.437c9.083 0 15.044 4.92 15.044 12.474 0 5.302-4.01 10.049-9.119 10.88v.277C75.317 46.394 80 51.21 80 57.863zM60.521 28.34H49.948v14.934h8.905c6.884 0 10.68-2.772 10.68-7.727 0-4.643-3.264-7.207-9.012-7.207zM49.948 49.2v16.458H60.91c7.167 0 10.964-2.876 10.964-8.281 0-5.406-3.903-8.178-11.425-8.178H49.948z"></path>
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="home" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path d="M8.354 1.146a.5.5 0 0 0-.708 0l-6 6A.5.5 0 0 0 1.5 7.5v7a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h4.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-4h2v4a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5H14a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-7a.5.5 0 0 0-.146-.354L13 5.793V2.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1.293L8.354 1.146zM2.5 14V7.707l5.5-5.5 5.5 5.5V14H10v-4a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v4H2.5z"/>
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="speedometer2" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V4.5A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4zM3.732 5.732a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0l.915.914a.5.5 0 1 1-.708.708l-.914-.915a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.707zM2 10a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h1.586a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H2.5A.5.5 0 0 1 2 10zm9.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H12a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm.754-4.246a.389.389 0 0 0-.527-.02L7.547 9.31a.91.91 0 1 0 1.302 1.258l3.434-4.297a.389.389 0 0 0-.029-.518z"/>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 10a8 8 0 1 1 15.547 2.661c-.442 1.253-1.845 1.602-2.932 1.25C11.309 13.488 9.475 13 8 13c-1.474 0-3.31.488-4.615.911-1.087.352-2.49.003-2.932-1.25A7.988 7.988 0 0 1 0 10zm8-7a7 7 0 0 0-6.603 9.329c.203.575.923.876 1.68.63C4.397 12.533 6.358 12 8 12s3.604.532 4.923.96c.757.245 1.477-.056 1.68-.631A7 7 0 0 0 8 3z"/>
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="table" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path d="M0 2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h12a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2zm15 2h-4v3h4V4zm0 4h-4v3h4V8zm0 4h-4v3h3a1 1 0 0 0 1-1v-2zm-5 3v-3H6v3h4zm-5 0v-3H1v2a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h3zm-4-4h4V8H1v3zm0-4h4V4H1v3zm5-3v3h4V4H6zm4 4H6v3h4V8z"/>
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="people-circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path d="M11 6a3 3 0 1 1-6 0 3 3 0 0 1 6 0z"/>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 8a8 8 0 1 1 16 0A8 8 0 0 1 0 8zm8-7a7 7 0 0 0-5.468 11.37C3.242 11.226 4.805 10 8 10s4.757 1.225 5.468 2.37A7 7 0 0 0 8 1z"/>
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="grid" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path d="M1 2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 2.5 1h3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 7 2.5v3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 5.5 7h-3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1 5.5v-3zM2.5 2a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-3zm6.5.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 10.5 1h3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 15 2.5v3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 13.5 7h-3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 9 5.5v-3zm1.5-.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-3zM1 10.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 2.5 9h3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 7 10.5v3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 5.5 15h-3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1 13.5v-3zm1.5-.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-3zm6.5.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 10.5 9h3a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.5 1.5v3a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5 1.5h-3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 9 13.5v-3zm1.5-.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-3z"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>

<main class="d-flex flex-nowrap">



  <div class="b-example-divider b-example-vr"></div>

  <div class="flex-shrink-0 p-3" style="width: 280px;">
    <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center pb-3 mb-3 link-body-emphasis text-decoration-none border-bottom">
      <svg class="bi pe-none me-2" width="30" height="24"><use xlink:href="#bootstrap"/></svg>
      <span class="fs-5 fw-semibold">Dashboard</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="list-unstyled ps-0">
      <li class="mb-1">
        <button class="btn btn-toggle d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded border-0 collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#home-collapse" aria-expanded="true">
          Home
        </button>
        <div class="collapse show" id="home-collapse">
          <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
            <li><a href="try.html" class="link-body-emphasis d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">Overview</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-body-emphasis d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">aaaaaaa</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-body-emphasis d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">bbbbbbbbb</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="mb-1">
        <button class="btn btn-toggle d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded border-0 collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#dashboard-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
          Two
        </button>
        <div class="collapse" id="dashboard-collapse">
          <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
            <li><a href="#" class="link-body-emphasis d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">Overview</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-body-emphasis d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">Weekly</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-body-emphasis d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">Monthly</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-body-emphasis d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">Annually</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="mb-1">
        <button class="btn btn-toggle d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded border-0 collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#orders-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
          Orders
        </button>
        <div class="collapse" id="orders-collapse">
          <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
            <li><a href="#" class="link-body-emphasis d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">New</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-body-emphasis d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">Processed</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-body-emphasis d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">Shipped</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-body-emphasis d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">Returned</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="border-top my-3"></li>
      <li class="mb-1">
        <button class="btn btn-toggle d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded border-0 collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#account-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
          Account
        </button>
        <div class="collapse" id="account-collapse">
          <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
            <li><a href="#" class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">New...</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">Sign out</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>


  <div class="b-example-divider b-example-vr"></div>
</main>
<script src="../assets/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <script src="sidebars.js"></script></body>


  </body>
</html>
```

**sidebars.js**

```
/* global bootstrap: false */
(() => {
  'use strict'
  const tooltipTriggerList = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
  tooltipTriggerList.forEach(tooltipTriggerEl => {
    new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
  })
})()
```

**try.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-bs-theme="auto">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>

    <p>Provaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

**sidebars.css**

```
.bd-placeholder-img {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  text-anchor: middle;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
  }
}

.b-example-divider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border: solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  border-width: 1px 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 .5em 1.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), inset 0 .125em .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

.b-example-vr {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 100vh;
}

.bi {
  vertical-align: -.125em;
  fill: currentColor;
}

.nav-scroller {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 2.75rem;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.nav-scroller .nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-top: -1px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.btn-bd-primary {
  --bd-violet-bg: #712cf9;
  --bd-violet-rgb: 112.520718, 44.062154, 249.437846;

  --bs-btn-font-weight: 600;
  --bs-btn-color: var(--bs-white);
  --bs-btn-bg: var(--bd-violet-bg);
  --bs-btn-border-color: var(--bd-violet-bg);
  --bs-btn-hover-color: var(--bs-white);
  --bs-btn-hover-bg: #6528e0;
  --bs-btn-hover-border-color: #6528e0;
  --bs-btn-focus-shadow-rgb: var(--bd-violet-rgb);
  --bs-btn-active-color: var(--bs-btn-hover-color);
  --bs-btn-active-bg: #5a23c8;
  --bs-btn-active-border-color: #5a23c8;
}
.bd-mode-toggle {
  z-index: 1500;
}

.dropdown-toggle { outline: 0; }

.btn-toggle {
  padding: .25rem .5rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: var(--bs-emphasis-color);
  background-color: transparent;
}
.btn-toggle:hover,
.btn-toggle:focus {
  color: rgba(var(--bs-emphasis-color-rgb), .85);
  background-color: var(--bs-tertiary-bg);
}

.btn-toggle::before {
  width: 1.25em;
  line-height: 0;
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3e%3cpath fill='none' stroke='rgba%280,0,0,.5%29' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-width='2' d='M5 14l6-6-6-6'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
  transition: transform .35s ease;
  transform-origin: .5em 50%;
}

[data-bs-theme="dark"] .btn-toggle::before {
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3e%3cpath fill='none' stroke='rgba%28255,255,255,.5%29' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-width='2' d='M5 14l6-6-6-6'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

.btn-toggle[aria-expanded="true"] {
  color: rgba(var(--bs-emphasis-color-rgb), .85);
}
.btn-toggle[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.btn-toggle-nav a {
  padding: .1875rem .5rem;
  margin-top: .125rem;
  margin-left: 1.25rem;
}
.btn-toggle-nav a:hover,
.btn-toggle-nav a:focus {
  background-color: var(--bs-tertiary-bg);
}

.scrollarea {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: You want load without page refresh (ajax) or with page refresh when you click on link ?

Comment: @Murtaza Bhurgri  Preferably without page refresh. If it's too complicated, then it's fine with page refresh too. Can you help me? Thank you